# How do I install an older version of a program?

Tags: 14.04, vino

I need to install an older version of vino to get around [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=726137)

How do I do that?

Specifically, I have xubuntu 14.04, freshly installed.  Vino no longer wants to talk with my phone :(.  14.04 comes with vino 3.8.1.  Previously, I was using 12.04 which had vino 3.4.2 which did work.  Until they fix this bug, how to get around this?

BTW, yes, this is also in ubuntu's bug tracker: [1290666](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/1290666).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before downgrading to the 13.10 version, try the workaround proposed in this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/1281250) report (disabling the encryption completely), by typing the following command in a Terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

To downgrade a package please visit [How do I downgrade to Subversion 1.6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205342/how-do-i-downgrade-to-subversion-1-6)

In your case just update (temporarily) the sources.list file not with precise but saucy.

Once done, don't forget to lock the version with:

```
echo subversion hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: Ah - I hadn't seen that bug report, and thus that workaround.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install <application X> <Version X>
```

"application X" is the application that you want and "Version X" is the version.  If you have application X installed at a newer version uninstall it by `sudo apt-get remove application X` to keep it configs files.  To remove the configs files `sudo apt-get purge application X`