# How to install an older version of a an application?

Tags: xfce, whisker

I've checked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454986/how-do-i-install-an-older-version-of-a-program) answer, but it didn't work for me.

I want to use the older version of `xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin`.
I issued the following command. (as per the instructions in the referred answer)

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin 1.4
```

It resulted as [this](https://pastebin.com/F4tLrwz8).

Can somebody guide me to install the older version of whisker menu which was a nice single-column menu bar?

Comment: Also include the *complete* output from your command not just the error message it says.

Comment: It's 16.4 with xfce4 desktop.

Comment: @ThomasWard https://pastebin.com/F4tLrwz8

Comment: My guess is that it's probably not possible. A plugin, by definition, fits into something else. So you'll need to downgrade other things. In any case, you first need to resolve the "you have held broken packages". That is a major issue by itself.

Comment: @DKBose Your guess was right. I tried `showpkg` command suggested by @ob2 which provides only version 1.5.1 (which is exactly what I have.) Can you suggest a way to resolve "you have held broken packages" issue?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages and other similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

Here how I downgrade a package. First look for available version:

```
apt-cache showpkg <pkg_name>
```

Check available version under `Provides:`. Then downgrade your package with

```
apt install <pkg_name>=<version>
```

By exemple for me:

```
apt-cache showpkg xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin
```

Returns:

```
Provides: 
2.3.1-1 - 
1.6.2-1 -
```

Finally to install version 1.6.2-1 (in case of 2.3.1-1 is installed)

```
apt install xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin=1.6.2-1
```

Note that command can fails if some dependencies needs to be downgraded as well.